# How to understand the dimension change about numpy dot production for 1d array and 2d array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two arrays, a and b.

```
In [168]: a.shape
Out[168]: (20, 3)

In [169]: b.shape
Out[169]: (20,)
```

The dot product of these two is

```
In [171]: numpy.dot(b, a).shape
Out[171]: (3,)
```

I do not understand why to get `(3,)`. What exactly `numpy.dot` does for a and b?

In my understanding, the mechanism behind might like this:

```
numpy.dot(a.T, b)
```

This makes sense because of `(3, 20) * (20,) -> (3,)`. But why `numpy.dot(b, a)`, `(20,) * (20, 3)`, also get `(3,)`?

Comment: @anky_91 It is different from my question. The question in the link is to ask why `(3, 20) * (20,) -> (3,)`, but my question is why `(20,) * (20, 3)`, also get `(3,)`

Comment: `dot` explains what happens when either argument is 1d.

Comment: @anky_91 I have read the doc but still could not get the idea.

Comment: np.matmul describes similar calculations with reshapes to (20,1) or (1,20) to perform standard 2d matrix product.

Comment: The np.matmul says `If the first argument is 1-D, it is promoted to a matrix by prepending a 1 to its dimensions. After matrix multiplication the prepended 1 is removed.` In this case, `(20,)` becomes  `(1, 20)`. And `(1, 20) * (20, 3) -> (1, 3)`. Then prepended 1 is removed, so we get `(3,)`. Is my understanding right?

Comment: Yes, the goal is to pair the last of `A` with the 2nd to the last of `B` (in `A@B`).  I also like to test ideas with `einsum`, where the basic `dot` indexing is `ij,jk->ik`.  `i` or `k` can be omitted and the sum of products on `j` still works.